# Create a new type of array in C#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to create a new type in C# from an existing type. This is possible in C quite easily, but I cannot figure out how this is done in C#. Something like this:

```
type Map int[,]
```

Comment: Do you mean to create an object of User-defined arrey?

Comment: Instead of int[,] I want to use Map. It will increase the code readability and also force type.

Comment: Create an object is not the same as create a type. I think you mean create a type.

Comment: Is `Map` is more a type or an alias?

Comment: Is there a way to achieve both? (Type and alias) If not how you would do only alias in C#?

Comment: are you talking about C typedef ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, and no, as far as I know.

## Inheritance

You can't inherit from an array type.

Quoting from the C# 5.0 spec, section 10.1.4.1,

> The direct base class of a class type must not be any of the following types: `System.Array`, `System.Delegate`, `System.MulticastDelegate`, `System.Enum`, or `System.ValueType`. Furthermore, a generic class declaration cannot use `System.Attribute` as a direct or indirect base class.

The closest I can think is adding an extension method, but of course that's not what you're looking for.

## Aliases

Aliases can be set up using `using` directives at the top of the code file:

```
using Map = System.Int32;
```

But that doesn't support array types, from what I can find.

Quoting from the C# 5.0 spec, section 9.4.1, a `using` alias looks like,

> using   identifier   =   namespace-or-type-name   ;

And `namespace-or-type-name` is defined in section 3.8, and doesn't mention anything about array types.

Answer (score 2):

if your only purpose in to "use Map instead of int[,]", you can create Map class with indexed property

```
public class Map
{
  private int[,] _map;

  public Map(int rows, int columns)
  {
    // rows, columns validation here
    _map = new int[rows, columns];
  }

  public int this[int r, int c]
  {
    get { return _map[r,c]; }
    set { _map[r,c] = value; }
  }
}
```

not so short as `type Map int[,]`, but provides the desired result. Example:

```
Map m = new Map(4,4);
m[2,2] = 1;
```